# "Counterexample" to Weyl's criterion on spectrum

Tags: complex-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be a bounded self-adjoint (or normal) operator on Hilbert space $H$. **Weyl's criterion** states that $\lambda \in\sigma(A)$ iff there exists sequence $\{x_n\}\subset H$ such that  $\|x_n\|=1$ and $\|Ax_n-\lambda x_n\|\rightarrow 0$.

What I'm looking for is "counterexamples" to this statement. By that I mean an example of not self-adjoin operator for which the statement does not hold. The structure of proof makes me think that this should be like that: we should observe that $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$ BUT the sequence above does not exist, but I struggle with constructing the example itself.

So, any hint appreciated!

Comment: What about $H=\ell^2$, $A$ the right shift operator, so that $1/2\in \sigma(A)$, but $\| (A-1/2)x\| \geq \| Ax\|- 1/2\|x\| = 1/2\|x\|$ for any $x\in H$.

Comment: The conclusion is true for any bounded operator on a Banach space if $\lambda$ is a boundary point of $\sigma(A).$

Comment: Any isometry $T$ such that $T(H)\subsetneq H$ is a counterexample with $\lambda =0.$